# How to convert JSON string in data frame column into multiple columns

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a data frame with a `JSON` string in a column:

| ID | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | {'Name': 'Sam', 'Age': 21} |
| 22 | {'Name': 'Nam', 'Age': 22} |
| 33 | {'Name': 'Pam', 'Age': 21, 'Salary': 10000} |

How can I convert the above `JSON` string in to columns?

Desired result:

| ID | Name | Age | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Sam | 21 |  |
| 22 | Nam | 22 |  |
| 33 | Pam | 21 | 10000 |

Comment: You want to convert to dataframe without pandas?

Comment: I am using pandas

Comment: so it must be present in a string format, right? not in json format

Comment: Yes, its string type but JSON format. @HimanshuPOddar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to read your column of dictionaries values into columns.

##### Creating the data

```
data = {
    'Id' : [11, 22, 33],
    'Data': ["{'Name': 'Sam', 'Age': 21}", "{'Name': 'Nam', 'Age': 22}", "{'Name': 'Pam', 'Age': 21, 'Salary': 10000}"],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Converting dictionary to column

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].map(lambda x: eval(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("Data").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

##### Output :

```
   Id Name  Age   Salary
0  11  Sam   21      NaN
1  22  Nam   22      NaN
2  33  Pam   21  10000.0
```

##### Alternate solution

You can also use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to unravel the dictionary column to column from dictionary keys.

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].map(lambda x: eval(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df.pop("Data"))], axis=1)
```

which gives you same output

Comment: Is there a way we can get the column list out of it which are added by the json string?
col = {'Name','Age','Salary'}

Comment: yes, we can use `df.pop("Data").apply(pd.Series).columns` this gives you  `['Name', 'Age', 'Salary']` there are various other ways of doing this